# HP NC362i Integrated DP Gigabit Server Adapter #2 Network link is disconnected

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am using leaseweb dedicated server. Recently server became unavailable. I had to use forced restart via management panel of leaseweb. I am checking errors and i found these 2 errors below

```
    HP NC362i Integrated DP Gigabit Server Adapter #2
Network link is disconnected.
```

another error

```
    Event filter with query "SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceModificationEvent 
WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 
"Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" 
could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" 
because of error 0x80041003. 
Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.
```

Does anybody know anything about this errors ?

I am using windows server 2008 r2 and asp.net 4.0

thank you

Comment: There's a NIC (probably built into the MB), it's second port isn't plugged in or has a flaky connection. The second error is that a WMI Event isn't firing because the processor is pegged. Really can't help more than that... The server being unavailable probably has to do with a disconnected network cable (or unreliable connection) or the processor being pegged.

Comment: Now when i forcefully restart the server becomes available again. I wonder which one of those is the cause. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I would contact LeaseWeb with the details and see what their support has to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is caused by the link dropping for some reason or another. This could be a problem with the NIC, the cable, or the switch it's connected to. Contact your host about this, as it's not a problem you can resolve.

The second error [is a known issue and this TechNet article has a fix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2545227). Essentially, it was an "oops" by whomever created the 2008 R2 SP1 .iso.

From that article:

> This originated in the Windows 7 SP1 DVD/ISO creation process. There was an issue in the creation process that caused a WMI registration to remain in the DVD/ISO. Since the registration is designed to work only during the DVD/ISO creation process, it fails to run on a live system and causes these events. These events are not indicative of any issue in the system and can be safely ignored. If however you want to prevent these events from getting generated and want to remove this specific WMI registration manually, please follow the steps mentioned in this article for running the workaround script.